# Canonical double format from ecmascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, double, ieee

I'm trying to figure out what exactly the ECMAScript of a non-integral number is. I believe this is covered under: double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE [here](https://262.ecma-international.org/). However, what might be some practical examples of formatting? For example, given the following numbers:

```
1.2
1.2e0
-1.2
.00005
-0.00005
```

Is there a function or something similar that will do a `toString()` or something that gives the scientific notation from the standard, such as `1.2E+0` or whatever it may be.

Comment: [`new Intl.NumberFormat('en', { notation: 'scientific' }).format(-1.2) // "-1.2E0"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#options)

Comment: @evolutionxbox that gives a different format, than say doing `num.toExponential()` -- which one of those is the "ECMAScript" format? -- `1.2e+0`.

Comment: What do you mean by "ECMAScript format"?